# Getting a FileNotFoundException when trying to make a SQLite connection in .net MAUI on Android

Tags: sqlite, .net-maui

db = new SQLiteConnection(databasePath);

The above statement works fine on Windows but gets the below error on Android. It also worked fine in xamarin forms on both platforms.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl, Version=2.0.4.976, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b68184102cba0b3b' or one of its dependencies.'

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The error happens on real Android device or Android emulators?Have you installed all the necessary nuget packages?Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a few things that you need take care of when using `sqlite` in your `MAUI` project.

**1**.Make sure you have installed below nuget packages:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.8.116" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLiteNetExtensions.Async" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.core" Version="2.1.0-pre20220207221914" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" Version="2.1.0-pre20220207221914" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl" Version="2.1.0-pre20220207221914" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.sqlite3" Version="2.1.0-pre20220207221914" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**2**.Use `SQLiteAsyncConnection` to initialize the database connection.

```
Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);
```

And then create static class Constants like below:

```
 public static class Constants
    {
        public const string DatabaseFilename = "MySQLite.db3";
        public const SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags Flags =
            SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite |
            SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.Create |
            SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache;
        public static string DatabasePath
        {
            get
            {
                var basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
                return Path.Combine(basePath, DatabaseFilename);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: both `SQLiteAsyncConnection` and `SQLiteConnection` give me runtime errors.

Comment: For a week I've been looking for a solution, turns out it was just adding a few more packages... Thanks a lot for making my day!

Comment: This just solved all my problems with SQLite not starting up
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

I installed the package SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same exception.

It was caused by having **spaces** in the **Project** Name